# OnComm event does not trigger

Tags: excel, vba, mscomm32

I'm trying to get the input of a 3g modem when it receives sms.

This is the code I'm using to trap any incoming sms.

```
Private Sub MSComm1_OnComm()
   Select Case MSComm1.CommEvent
      Case comEvReceive
         Do While MSComm1.InBufferCount > 0
            strInput = strInput & MSComm1.Input
         Loop

         Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Text = strInput
   End Select
End Sub
```

Regardless the code, the event does not fire as if nothing is received.

What do I miss here?

Thank u.

Comment: Is your `InBufferCount` <= 0?  Are you sure `MSComm1.InBufferCount` is populating correctly?

Comment: As I said.. the event does not trigger regardless the code.. assume that the code is 100% correct, the problem is that the MSComm does not feel that something is received by the modem.

Comment: I found that in another thread.. In order for the OnComm event to fire, you need to set RThreshold and SThreshold to 1. So how to implement that?

Comment: page 338?
 https://www.8051projects.net/files/public/1189441710_383_FT2138_vbcom.pdf

Comment: thank u. I know how to write this. I only can't understand where to put it in the code.